how to collect returned results of promises
as shown in the below posted code, for the array geoTIFFsFileNames it contains five files' names. for the number of items in the latter array, i want to invoke the webservice
WSGeoTIFFAsBlobStreamer, and for each invokation to it there are some data to be returned correspond to the file name.
i want to have the executions or the invokations to the webservice to be done async, so i created the array promises to collect the promises returned from .stream
then, i executed all the pushed promises as follows:
await Promise.all(promises)

i expected that the response in the .then() of await Promise.all(promises) is to contain all the responses for the five times invokations to the webservice, but at run time,
the response in the .then() of await Promise.all(promises) contains only one response.!! i expected to have five responses where there is a response to be returned for each
time the webservice is invoked
please let me know how the code can be modified so the the response in the .then() of await Promise.all(promises) returns five responses as the webservice gets invoked five
times
code:
const promises = new Array();  
promises.push(geoTIFFsFileNames.map((geoTIFFFileName, index) => {
    this.#geoTIFFOverlayBlobStreamingStates.value = GeoTIFFOverlayBlobStreamingStates.CONST_STREAMING.description;
    this.#wsGeoTIFFAsBlobStreamer = new WSGeoTIFFAsBlobStreamer(geoTIFFFileName);
    this.#wsGeoTIFFAsBlobStreamer.setRequestOptionsParams();
    return this.#wsGeoTIFFAsBlobStreamer.stream((geoTIFFFileName, asBlob, asURL, state) => {
        this.#msg = ({msg:infoTag + 'connectWSGeoTIFFsAsBlobsStreamerFor().',
            url: `${endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_LOCAL_HOST_3000.description}${endPointsURLs.VUE_NEWSWM_APP_PATH.description}${BackendWssConstants.CONST_WS_GEOTIFF_AS_BLOB_STREAMER.description}/${geoTIFFFileName}`,
            asBlob: asBlob,
            asURL: asURL,
            state: state,
        });
        console.info(this.#msg);
        return [geoTIFFFileName, asBlob, asURL, state];
    })
}));
await Promise.all(promises)
.then(response => {
    this.#msg = {msg:verboseTag + 'xcx connectWSGeoTIFFsAsBlobsStreamerFor().', response: response};
    console.log(this.#msg);
    this.#geoTIFFOverlayBlobStreamingStates.value = GeoTIFFOverlayBlobStreamingStates.CONST_BLOB_OBTAINED.description;
    this.#setWSGeoTIFFAsBlobStreamerResults({
        order: order,
        geoTIFFFileName: response[0],
        asBlob: response[1],
        asURL: response[2],
        state: response[3],
    });
    resolve(response);
    onResult(response[0], response[1], response[2], response[3]);
})
.catch(err => {
    this.#geoTIFFOverlayBlobStreamingStates.value = GeoTIFFOverlayBlobStreamingStates.CONST_ERROR_OCCURED.description;
    this.#msg = JSON.stringify({msg:WTFTag + 'connectWSGeoTIFFsAsBlobsStreamerFor.value. Error impeded ws from successful execution and return:',
        ws:BackendWssConstants.CONST_WS_GEOTIFF_AS_BLOB_STREAMER.description,
        geoTIFFsFileNames: geoTIFFsFileNames,
        error: err,
    });
    console.error(this.#msg);
    reject({msg:errorTag + 'faild to fetch: ' + BackendWssConstants.CONST_WS_GEOTIFF_AS_BLOB_STREAMER.description + ' rejected promise', err:err});
    onResult(null, null, null);
    throw new Error(this.#msg);
});


Uh, what's the deal with this.#geoTIFFOverlayBlobStreamingStates, this.#wsGeoTIFFAsBlobStreamer and this.#msg? Why use private instance fields, which are shared for all five iterations, instead of normal local variables?

promises.push(geoTIFFsFileNames.map(…)) is wrong. You want either const promises = new Array();   promises.push(...geoTIFFsFileNames.map(…)) or just const promises = geoTIFFsFileNames.map(…)!

Edit
const promises = geoTIFFsFileNames.map((geoTIFFFileName, index) => {
    // assuming this returns a Promise
    return this.#wsGeoTIFFAsBlobStreamer.stream( ... )
}));

// either you await and get an Array with the resolved Promises
const responses = await Promise.all(promises)
for (const response of responses) {
    // you now have each response here
}

// or you use then() without await
Promise.all(promises).then((responses) => {
    // responses is an Array with the individual results of the "stream()" Promises
    for (const response of responses) {
        // you now have each response here
    }
})


thank you. do you mean the code i provided is correct? and do not need to be modified?but then , why i am getting only one result

const promises = geoTIFFsFileNames.map(.... etc that way you'll have an array of Promises, rather than an array where the first element is an array of promises
